# Simple PHP login form not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to create a VERY basic login request page with no security (i'm just learning the fundamentals).

I currently have a database and a table created on phpmyadmin with 1 tuple consisting of an email and password (as well as other information).

I've created a HTML form which consists of two input fields for email, password and a submit button which sends the user to a new **sign-in-script.php** page.

My HTML:

```
<form action="sign-in-script.php" method="GET">  
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>                      
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit" />
```

**sign-in-script.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

$servername = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = 'root';

$email = $_GET['email']; 
$user_password = $_GET['password']; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 

if($conn->connect_error) { 
    die ('Connection Failed'); 
} else { 
    echo ('Connection Established <br>'); 

    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'Oreon')) { 
        die('Database could not be reached ' . $conn->error); 
    } else { 
        echo ('Database Reached <br> '); 
        echo $email; 
        echo '<br>';
        echo $user_password; 

        $sign_in_token = "SELECT * FROM core_customer_information WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$user_password."' LIMIT 1"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($sign_in_token); 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) { 
            echo "You have successfully logged in"; 
        } else { 
            die ("Incorrect email address or password: " . $conn->error); 
        }
    } // close brackets db selected 
}
}
```

I've made sure multiple times that the email and password i've entered match those saved in the db but it's still returning as 'incorrect email or password' and I'm unsure why.

I've took the SQL query and ran it directly in phpmyadmin at the query returns the tuple i'm supposed to return so pretty unsure why it is not working in my script.

I would appreciate some help if possible.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time in advance.

Comment: You are creating `mysqli` connection and using `mysql_query`

Comment: Use quota in the email and password. like: `WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$user_password."'`

Answer (score 0):

mixed use of mysql and mysqli.

try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

$servername = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = 'root';

$email = $_GET['email']; 
$user_password = $_GET['password']; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 

if($conn->connect_error) { 
    die ('Connection Failed'); 
} else { 
    echo ('Connection Established <br>'); 

    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'Oreon')) { 
        die('Database could not be reached ' . $conn->error); 
    } else { 
        echo ('Database Reached <br> '); 
        echo $email; 
        echo '<br>';
        echo $user_password; 

        $sign_in_token = "SELECT * FROM core_customer_information WHERE email=".$email." AND password=".$user_password." LIMIT 1"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sign_in_token); 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) { 
            echo "You have successfully logged in"; 
        } else { 
            die ("Incorrect email address or password: " . $conn->error); 
        }
    } // close brackets db selected 
}
}
```

Comment: Ahh right thank you. It's because I was using w3 schools to create the connection then following a Youtube tutorial for the rest. Thank for your help and i'll accept your answer when I can!